# Why isn't AWS elastic beanstalk copying my nginx custom configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having some issues in configuring elastic beanstalk to run 2 asp.net core APIs on a Linux environment. What I am trying to do is to deploy a service called audit which runs on port 5005 and one called idp which runs on port 5000.

What is happening is that I can access idp APIs but not the audit  APIs.

This is what my zip upload looks like:

audit/**
idp/**
.platform/ngnix/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/01_custom.conf
Procfile
01_cusom.conf contain:

```
location /audit{
     proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5005 ;
     proxy_http_version  1.1;

     proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header   Connection $http_connection;
     proxy_set_header   Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

location /idp{
     proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000 ;
     proxy_http_version  1.1;

     proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header   Connection $http_connection;
     proxy_set_header   Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Procfile contains:

```
audit: dotnet audit/audit.dll
idp: dotnet idp/idp.dll
```

audit and idp contains the dlls for each of my applications.

Based on the documentation what should happen is that the configuration set in .platform/ngnix/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/01_custom.conf should be set in nginx on the machine. This is not actually happening. I have connected to the machine and found that only a file with the default configuration exists on the machine.

To make sure this is the issue I added from the deployed zip (.platform/ngnix/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/01_custom.conf) in /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application_conf and then restarted the nginx server. This actually solves my issue.

So the problem seems to be that the deployment mechanism is not working as documented. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-linux-platform-nginx.html)

Does anyone have a solution for this?

**EDIT**

I have tried putting 01_custom.conf in the following places and non seem to work:

- .platform/ngnix/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/
- .platform/ngnix/conf.d/
- .platform/ngnix with the file 01_custom.conf
- .platform/ngnix with the file nginx.conf file with the hope of overriding the one in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: Are you certain you are using EB based on Amazon Linux 2, not Amazon Linux 1. Also if you exposed second port, have you adjusted security groups for that?

Comment: Super late to this, but did you ever figure out a solution? I'm running into the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The folder where you should put your custom nginx script is at .platform/nginx/conf.d/

Don't put it at elasticbeanstalk/01_custom.conf

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

Comment: I have tryed multiple variations on this tryed putting it in .platform/ngnix/conf.d/ also tryed putting it in .platform/ngnix non seem to work.

Comment: Maybe is the port of /idp. It's the port 5000 of nginx default configuration. Can you try changing it?

Comment: As I mentioned in the questioned I logged on the machine and added the nginx configuration manualy after adding the configuration I can call both the idp and the audit apis.